# morquee scroling left (fething from deta) , scroll one by one but all images scroll

Tags: php, sql

I am adding images from data in marquee wen direction is up it works fine but when direction is left  all images  collectively goes from right to left. I need one by one scroll.

```
<div id="right">
    <td height="auto" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="index-unwel" >
         <marquee direction="left" scrollamount="2" height="250" onmouseover="this.stop();"   onmouseout="this.start();">
            <div align="left" style="width:100% ;">
            <span style="text-transform:uppercase;"> 
              <?
                $qryAdv = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".VIDEONEWS." WHERE 1");
                if(mysql_num_rows($qryAdv) > 0)
                {
                    while($adv = mysql_fetch_assoc($qryAdv))
                    {
              ?>
             <a href="<?=$adv['adv_url']?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?=VIDEO.$adv['adv']?>" width="100%"></a> <br /> <br />

              <?
                    }
                } else { echo 'NO VIDEO NEWS FOUND!!!'; }
              ?>
         </marquee>
    </td>
```

I have used

```
while($adv = mysql_fetch_array($qryAdv))
```

in-spite of

```
while($adv = mysql_fetch_assoc($qryAdv))
```

also but not successful.

Comment: Wow, <marquee> tag? I thought it was deprecated 20 years ago

Comment: `when direction is left all images collectively goes from right to left` - well that is exact what is supposed to happen when you use `left` - look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee with `<marquee>This text will scroll from right to left</marquee>` (`left` is default, and goes from right to left)

Comment: Sir if u have the new one plz  fit my requirement ie fetching data in java query and post here

Comment: Sir all images vertically goes from right to left not horizontal y   all pictures move collectively (in vertical order)  Sean sir ji

Comment: Ill just leave this here.... http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/

Comment: cycle2 used problem solved

Answer (score 0):

in spite of marquee cycle2 used it is easy. Thanks to    prodigitalson     Link from where i downloaded the cycle2 is jquery.malsup.com/cycle2 
Thanks for your suggestion which lead me to a new era.